# MySql Join slow with SUM() of results

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery, left-join

anyone know a more efficient way to execute this query?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.*, IFNULL(SUM(v.visits),0) AS visits,
FROM posts AS p 

LEFT JOIN visits_day v ON v.post_id=p.post_id 

GROUP BY post_id 
ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

The visits_day table has one record per day, per user, per post. With the growth of the table this query is extremely slow.

I cant add a column with the total visit count because I need to list the posts by more visits per day or per week, etc.

Does anyone know a beter solution to this?

Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE `visits_day` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `day` date NOT NULL,
 `visits` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52302 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `link` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
 `img` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1027 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

With `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, the query must evaluate everything, just not deliver all the rows.  Getting rid of that should be beneficial.

To actually touch only 20 rows, we need to get through the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` with a single index.  Otherwise, we might have to touch all the rows, sort them then deliver 20.  The obvious index is `(post_id)`; I suspect that is already indexed as `PRIMARY KEY(post_id)`?  (It would help if you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` when asking questions.)

Another way to do the join, and get the desired result of zero, is as follows.  Note that it eliminates the need for `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT p.*,
       IFNULL( ( SELECT SUM(v.visits)
                   FROM visits_day
                   WHERE post_id = p.post_id
               ),
            0) AS visits
    FROM posts AS p 
    ORDER BY post_id DESC
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

If you really need the count, then consider `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts`.

`ON v.post_id=p.post_id` in your query and `WHERE post_id = p.post_id` beg for `INDEX(post_id)` on `visits_day`.  That will speed up both variants considerably.

Comment: Thanks Rick, it was a good idea. But the problem continues when I need to filter the posts per visit, using order by. =(

Comment: @FelipeB. - Eh?  I thought my version would give the same results.

Comment: When I remove the ORDER BY, it gets very fast. But I need to ORDER BY visits it is slow again. I inserted the tables if it helps.

Comment: Missing an 'obvious' index.